# Vaadin >=v22: how does one properly logout of a session?

Tags: vaadin

I was trying to locate some description or example how one properly logs out of a Vaadin application. In my application I want to provide a "logout" button or link that erases/clears the session so that one subsequently has to log in again. How does one do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    // logout button
    Button logoutButton = new Button("Logout", VaadinIcon.SIGN_OUT.create());
    logoutButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY, ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR, ButtonVariant.LUMO_SMALL);
    logoutButton.addClickListener(e -> {
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().invalidate();
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().reload();
    });
```